# Spring Integration DSL JMS and CrudRepository with transaction control

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

I am reading a message from JMS and as I progress through the integration flow I am building a number objects and am adding them to the header. Later in the flow  I wish to save the objects to the database. I am using `CrudRepository` - the examples in DSL JPA seem to be JPA related, but I cannot figure out how to do it for a `CrudRepository`.

I am defining the JMS transaction as follows;

```
@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}
```

The queue reader flow looks like this;

```
@Bean
public StandardIntegrationFlow queueReader(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
        Jms
        .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    Jms.container(connectionFactory, "myQueue")
                        .transactionManager(transactionManager(connectionFactory))
                        .get()
                )
        )
...
        .enrichHeaders(h -> h
                .headerFunction(H1, x-> new ClassA(), true)
                .headerFunction(H2, x-> new ClassB(), true)
        )
```

I know that the following part is wrong and somewhere I need an `EntityManager` - but I basically want to do ...

```
        .handle((p, h) -> {
                crudRepositoryA.save((ClassA) h.get(H1));
                return p;
        })
        .handle((p, h) -> { 
                //do something else
                return p;
        })
        .handle((p,h) -> {
                crudRepositoryB.save((ClassB) h.gey(H2));
                // done. No return.
        }
```

I assume that I should be using a `Jpa.updatingGateway`, but I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading the reference guide, the Java Configuration example was more intuitive than the DSL example. I wrongly assumed that I needed to call `.save()`

The modified code was first to add the `JpaTransaction` so that JMS and JPA are transacted together.

```
    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
        EntityManagerFactory entityManageFactory
    ) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(
            new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory),
            new JpaTransactionManager(entityManageFactory)
        );
            
    }
```

Then have the `handler` forward to a `channel` which does;

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow saveClassA() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(CHANNEL_TO_DATABASE)
            .handle((p, h)-> {
                return (ClassA) h.get(H1);
            })
            .handle(
                Jpa.outboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                    .entityClass(ClassA.class)
                    .persistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST)
                ,
                    e -> e.transactional()
            ).
            get();
    }
```

The above acts as the end of the flow. I would just use `Jpa.updatingGateway` if I wanted to continue the flow.

I would assume that this is not XA, but the database side will deal with duplicates and update instead of insert.